# Is it possible to get the keywords in the documents returned by Solr

Tags: solr

Solr provides an easy way to search documents based on keywords, but I was wondering if it had the ability to return the keywords themselves?

For example, I may want to search for all documents created by Joe Blogs last week and then get a feel for the contents of those documents by the keywords inside them. Or do I have to work out the key words myself and save them in a field?

Comment: What do you mean here by 'keywords'? For a phrase with 5 words in it, solr may create an index with dozens, hundreds or even thousands(based on applied analyzers/tokenizers) tokens which should match search keyword.. A lot of those won't make any sense to regular user.

Or are you asking about providing fragments of field which was matched, which is [highlighting](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Highlighting)?

Or do you mean that solr should 'guess' the content keywords? (e.g. topic, category, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming by keywords you mean the tokens that Solr generates when parsing a particular field, you may want to review the documentation and examples for [the Term Vector Component](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Term+Vector+Component).

Before implementing it though, just checking the Analysis screen of the Solr (4+) Admin WebUI, as it has a section that shows the terms/tokens particular field actually generates.

If these are not quite the keywords that you are trying to produce, you may need to have a separate field that generates those keywords, possibly by using [UpdateRequestProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor) in the indexing pipeline.

Finally, if you are trying to *get a feel* to do some sort of clustering, you may want to look at the [Carrot2](http://project.carrot2.org/), which already does this and integrates with Solr.

Comment: Thankyou - this is exactly what I was looking for. By _feel_ I was really thinking something along the lines of trending topics, and the clusters produced by something like carrot2 would appear to give me exactly that. The term vector component is also a nice fallback.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is know as "[Topic Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model)". Solr does not have out of the box support for this. However there are other tools that you can integrate to achieve this.

- Apache Mahout supports [LDA algorithm](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Latent+Dirichlet+Allocation), that can be used to model topics. There are several examples of integrating Solr with Mahout. Here is [one such](http://searchhub.org/2010/03/16/integrating-apache-mahout-with-apache-lucene-and-solr-part-i-of-3/).
- [Apache UIMA](http://uima.apache.org/) (Unstructured Information Management Applications.) I won't bother typing about it. Instead, here is a [brilliant presentation](http://vimeo.com/32406329).

Comment: UIMA/Solr integration looks interesting, but the default relies on having accounts with Alchemy API and Open Calais (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/UIMA+Integration), which is not ideal. But your idea led me to the book Taming Text, where chapter 8 (which is a free sample at http://www.manning.com/ingersoll/) demonstrates something similar with OpenNLP.